# jquery to disable form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Scenario is that I have written a function for auto refresh on form element and I want onclick event on login button to disable the auto refresh function.

I'm not able to get disable the autorefresh and the page still refreshes.

My code is:

```
$('#form').ready(function () { //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 15000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e){
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 2) { // 20 minutes
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

$('#login').ready(function () {

    alert("working promptly");
    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        alert("Hi In click !");
        $('#form').attr("disabled","true"); 
    });


});
```

Comment: `setInterval("timerIncrement()", 15000);` should be `setInterval("timerIncrement", 15000);` and omg, how many errors can you make in a script?

Comment: Actually, it should be `setInterval(timerIncrement, 15000);` - eval is evil!

Comment: @anu this is a very common problem, use `prop` instead of `attr` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are needing to *clear* the interval timer:

```
$(this).click(function (e) {
    alert("Hi In click !");
    $('#form').attr("disabled","true"); 
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
});
```